# Getting database row data and setting variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

For some reason cant get my head around this.

So I have multiple check boxes, and I want their variables to be dynamic.

I have made the db table as 'values' and then have 3 fields are 'id' 'name' 'value'

The aim is to query the database for all of the rows. And then set the variables for the input labels.

E.g:

```
$checkboxlabel = $row['value'];

<label><?php echo $checkboxlabel</label>
<label><?php echo $checkboxlabel2</label>
<label><?php echo $checkboxlabel3</label>
```

The db query etc is fine, but can't think how to possible pass an argument into the `$row`? or basically how to just assign the variable to the correct value I need.

The db structure is like so:

```
ID | NAME | VALUE

1  | checkboxlabel  | checkboxlabelValue
2  | checkboxlabel1 | checkboxlabel1Value
3  | checkboxlabel2 | checkboxlabel2Value
```

There will be around 50 checkboxes, so making a WHERE clause statement for everyone would be painful...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Why can't you just loop through the values returned from the db and fill them out as required?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query fetches all the fields, you can try following. Kindly note, I've not tested this.

```
$str='';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$str .='<label>'.$row["NAME"].'</label><input type="checkbox" id="'.$row["ID"].'" value="'.$row["VALUE"].'">';
}
echo $str;
```

**Note :** The mysql extension is deprecated and use of PDO or MYSQLI is recommended.